# Read/Write a dictionary with values as integer lists in a csv file in python 2.6.x

Tags: python, csv, dictionary

So I did lots of googling but still can't solve this problem.
I tried this:

```
import csv
mydict={4442:[4441,4442], 4441:[4441,4442]}
with open('testcsv.csv','wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        writer.writerow([key, value])
```

But this is completely not what I expected. Because it generates a csv file like:

```
4441 "[4441, 4442]"
4442 "[4441, 4442]"
```

I'll never get the dictionary value read as list but a string.
My read process is like:

```
result={}
try:
  reader = csv.reader(open('testcsv.csv', 'rb'))
  result = dict(x for x in reader)    #note: Everything turned to be string after reading from csv
  print "testcsv.csv found, load it from file."
except:
  print "testcsv.csv not found. loop all over."
```

And then my result changed to :

```
print result
print result[str(4442)]
print result[str(4441)]

{'4441': '[4441, 4442]', '4442': '[4441, 4442]'}
[4441, 4442]
[4441, 4442]
```

So my question is how to write / read as it is for a dictionary with integer list as its value ?

**Update Solution, accepted answer below will also work:**

```
for row in reader:
    if row[1][1:-1] != '':
        result[int(row[0])] = map(int, row[1][1:-1].split(','))
    else:
        result[int(row[0])] = []
```

Comment: what exactly is the expected output?

Comment: You wrote "I'll never get the dictionary value read as list but a string" -- that's because each row read from the csv file is returned as a list of strings. No automatic data type conversion is performed as stated in the second paragraph of the [documentation](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html?highlight=csv.reader#csv.reader). This means you'll need to do it yourself some way or another.

Comment: @martineau, thanks for pointing that out, I missed that part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Space is not a good delimiter here, because the string representation of the list contains a space. For my answer I'm using '|' as the delimiter.

To load the csv file so it creates a dict that is the same as the one you wrote, you can use something like this:

```
try:
  reader = csv.reader(open('bar.in', 'rb'), delimiter='|')
  result = dict((int(x[0]), eval(x[1])) for x in reader)
  print "testcsv.csv found, load it from file."
except:
  print "testcsv.csv not found. loop all over."
```

So now result is:

```
{4441: [4441, 4442], 4442: [4441, 4442]}
```

Where all the numbers are ints.  Remember though, this uses eval, and eval can be dangerous.

Comment: eval works here, but I guess it's a hack, since csv writer wrote only string for list type.

Comment: Well, only the list as a whole was converted to a string. Notice that in the csv file that the list is in double quotes, but the values aren't. Since the numbers are not in quotes they are eval'd as ints.

Answer (score 1):

This works (and doesn't use`eval()`). Note that the way the rows of the csv file are written is slightly different from your version.

```
import csv
mydict={4442:[4441,4442], 4441:[4441,4442]}
with open('testcsv.csv', 'wb') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f, delimiter=' ')
    for key, value in mydict.items():
        writer.writerow([key] + value)  # note difference from your version

try:
    reader = csv.reader(open('testcsv.csv', 'rb'), delimiter=' ')
    result = dict((row[0], row[1:]) for row in (map(int, row) for row in reader))
    print "testcsv.csv found, load it from file."
    print result
except Exception as e:
    print "testcsv.csv not found. loop all over."
    print e
```

Output:

```
testcsv.csv found, load it from file.
{4441: [4441, 4442], 4442: [4441, 4442]}
```

Note: The one-liner to create`result`is equivalent to:

```
result = {}
for row in (map(int, row) for row in reader):
    result[row[0]] = row[1:]
```

Comment: I tried your version, but it didn't work in my case, I'm not familiar with python one-liner coding.so I end up open it up as:`for row in reader:
    if row[1][1:-1] != '':
        result[int(row[0])] = map(int, row[1][1:-1].split(','))
    else:
        result[int(row[0])] = []`

Comment: I'm not sure what you're doing, but suspect that if my version didn't work for you it may have been because you didn't use the `writer.writerow([key] + value)` I have in the first for loop which writes the csv file. The creates rows that look like `4441 4441 4442` and `4442 4441 4442`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to have a flattened list like `[a,b,c...]` not `[a,[...],c,...]`

```
for key, value in mydict.items():
    writer.writerow([key]+ value)
```

Will output (first row)

```
4441 4441 4442
```

Comment: but in this way, it doesn't make sense as a dictionary format.